# RecyclerView deselect the previous selected checkbox

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm having the RecyclerView ViewHolder as checkbox, once the checkbox is clicked, i need to deselect the other checkbox which is already selected, but it is not happening, the changes are not reflected in the view.

The Recycler item click is initialised in onBindViewHolder on click, the slot data is updated and notifiedItemChanged is called but the placeholder is not updated, do i miss anything in updating the viewholders.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(
    holder: BookingSlotListItemViewHolder,
    position: Int,
    payloads: MutableList<Any?>
 )
```

---

```
class BookingSlotListAdapter(
    private val hourSlotHolder: RecyclerView,
    private val bookingBtn: TextView
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BookingSlotListItemViewHolder>() {
    private val bookingSlots = ArrayList<BookingSlotAvailability>()
    private var lastSelected: Int? = null
    private val bookingHourItemAdapter = BookingHourItemAdapter(bookingBtn)
    private val NOT_SELECTED_FOR_BOOKING = 0
    private val AVAILABLE_FOR_BOOKING = false

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BookingSlotListItemViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.booking_time_slot, parent, false)
        return BookingSlotListItemViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        if (bookingSlots.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        return 0
        }
        return bookingSlots.size
    }

    fun setBookingSlots(bookingSlots: TreeMap<String, Boolean>) {
        bookingSlots.map {
            this.bookingSlots.add(BookingSlotAvailability(it.key, it.value, NOT_SELECTED_FOR_BOOKING))
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BookingSlotListItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.timeSlot.text = bookingSlots[position].time
        if (!bookingSlots[position].isAvailable) {
        holder.timeSlot.isEnabled = false
        }
        if (bookingSlots[position].selectionStatus == 0 && holder.timeSlot.isChecked) {
        holder.timeSlot.toggle()
        } else if (bookingSlots[position].selectionStatus == 1 && !holder.timeSlot.isChecked) {
        holder.timeSlot.toggle()
        }

        holder.timeSlot.setOnClickListener { view: View? ->
        Log.v("CLICKED", "BookingSlotListAdapter: $lastSelected : $position")
        val selectedSlot = view as CheckBox

        if (lastSelected != null) {
            bookingSlots[lastSelected!!].isAvailable = AVAILABLE_FOR_BOOKING
            bookingSlots[lastSelected!!].selectionStatus = NOT_SELECTED_FOR_BOOKING
            notifyItemChanged(
            lastSelected,
            bookingSlots[lastSelected!!]
            )
        }
        bookingSlots[position].isAvailable = NOT_AVAILABLE
        bookingSlots[position].selectionStatus = SELECTED_FOR_BOOKING
        notifyItemChanged(
            position,
            bookingSlots[position]
        )
        lastSelected = position
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: BookingSlotListItemViewHolder,
        position: Int,
        payloads: MutableList<Any?>
    ) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
        Log.v("OVERLOADEDVH", "$payloads $position")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to make it check/unchecked in onBindViewholder method, because it reuses the view and creates view again when we scroll the recyclerView, So it doens't know the last state of checkBox :

```
    // Add these lines below at then end of onBindViewHolder
    val selectedSlot = holder.timeSlot as CheckBox

    if(lastSelected == position){
        selectedSlot.isChecked = true;
    }else{
        selectedSlot.isChecked = false;
    }
```

to update the old checkboxes to deselect, call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so `onBindHolder()` will be called again for all visible cells, and will update accordingly.

call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after when you are setting `lastSelected` pos :

```
    holder.timeSlot.setOnClickListener { view: View? ->
    Log.v("CLICKED", "BookingSlotListAdapter: $lastSelected : $position")
    val selectedSlot = view as CheckBox

    if (lastSelected != null) {
        bookingSlots[lastSelected!!].isAvailable = AVAILABLE_FOR_BOOKING
        bookingSlots[lastSelected!!].selectionStatus = NOT_SELECTED_FOR_BOOKING

        //COMMENT  notifyDataSetChanged WILL HANDLE ALL
        //notifyItemChanged(
        //lastSelected,
        //bookingSlots[lastSelected!!]
        //)
    }
    bookingSlots[position].isAvailable = NOT_AVAILABLE
    bookingSlots[position].selectionStatus = SELECTED_FOR_BOOKING

    //COMMENT  notifyDataSetChanged WILL HANDLE ALL
    //notifyItemChanged(
    //    position,
    //    bookingSlots[position]
    //)
    lastSelected = position

     //------CALL notifyDataSetChanged() for all visible cells------
     notifyDataSetChanged() ;


    }
```

Comment: yes, to the extent that whenever the control is reused, t he state is the same so it must be specifically checked AND unchecked.  A coworker of mine discovered this with buttons he was hiding.

Comment: @NehaK, I have handled it, the issue not while toggling the current checkbox to on state, i need to toggle the previous checkbox to off state, can you help me in that

Comment: It will update all the viewholders, i need to update only the affected viewholders, its all are time slots, there will be more than 30 placeholders will visible in the screen at a time